# Get Roslyn samples to work

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, roslyn

I am using Visual Studio 2013 SP1.

After installing Roslyn I wanted to play with the samples. In the samples folder there is a project called MakeConstCS. So I hit F5, the experimental VS env is loaded. Then I create a new project and boom.

*Normal Build Error incomplete  Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.CSharp, Version=0.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I get the same error when I try File->New->Project->Templates->C#->Roslyn->CodeRefactoring->F5

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Roslyn into your VS experimental hive.  This is listed in the Readme, and the SDK includes an exe to do so.

Correct way to reinstall Roslyn:

1. Uninstall all the Roslyn extensions
2. Delete *%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Roslyn*
3. Using regedit delete *HKCU\Software\Microsoft\visualStudio\12.0Roslyn* and *12.0Roslyn_Config*
4. Run *Install Roslyn Preview into Roslyn Experimental Hive.exe*
5. Run *Roslyn End User Preview.vsix*
6. Run *Roslyn SDK Project Templates.vsix*
7. Run *Roslyn Syntax Visualizer.vsix*

For debugging with VisualStudio2013

- Check the project file entry and use the correct version of your VS instance:
  `<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>`

Comment: What happens if you run "devenv /rootsuffix Roslyn" and then go to Tools/Extensions and Updates? Is Roslyn present and enabled?

Comment: Yes, it WAS presented there. And I was not able to open any code file like *.cs/vb in visual studio, VS just open a blank tab. That was the case earlier today. I reinstalled everything (different extensions install order) and the error went away but Roslyn is NOT presented in the Tools/Extensions.

Comment: Try deleting %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Roslyn, and using regedit to delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\visualStudio\12.0Roslyn and 12.0Roslyn_Config.  Then re-run the installer and try again.

Comment: OK. Now the errors are gone and Roslyn is showing in the Extensions window. Now I have to figure out why my VSIX extension is not loaded when I press F5. http://gyazo.com/bfa8f87692e1e2b98f8d8f63984a3961

Comment: Done. Now I am able to debug everything. In the project file I changed the VS version from 10.0->12.0; <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>

Comment: Are you using the September 2012 CTP, or the SDK that was released at //Build/

Comment: And what project files did you need to edit? Your own, or the samples?

Comment: After reinstalling Roslyn the samples are OK. But File->NewProject->Templates->C#->Roslyn projects need updates.

Comment: For VS 14 CTP 4 I can't figure out how to get Roslyn running in an experimental instance, but you can force it to copy to the standard instance and then remove the "/rootsuffix Roslyn" as described here: http://grahamthecoder.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/debugging-roslyn-extensions-for-vs-14-ctp-4/

Comment: You don't need to do anything to get Roslyn to run in an experimental version in VS "14".  It's always there by default in all instances.  Just make sure that you have the versions of the NuGet packages that match CTP4.